# Yeoman can never install generators

Tags: yeoman

I'm having a problem with yeoman on a couple platforms (Mac OS, Ubuntu).

Basically, the conundrum is that `yo` can never install generators because it tries to use the `-g` option but it needs root access in order to do that. However, you cannot run `sudo yo`. I imagine the "update generators" option would probably fail as well.

How do I fix it so I can do everything I need within `yo`, instead of quitting and manually running `sudo npm install -g generator-webapp` (e.g.)?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in my work laptop with MAC OS, I changed the owner and group of the .npm folder: /Users/eduardoc/.npm, to match my username and group. The -g option worked perfectly after that.

Comment: Is there a reason why `npm` installs with root as the owner instead of your user, and is it a "Bad Idea" to make this change?